# Where is the iterator interface implementation in Java 5 and above?

Tags: java, iterator

As Iterator is an interface with hasNext(), next() and remove() methods. But where is the implementation for all these methods in Java classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost every concrete collection has its own implementation, optimized for that specific collection. You don't have to bother about the details. But here are some examples:

- `LinkedList` - [`class ListItr implements ListIterator<E>`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#687)
- `ArrayList` - [`class ListItr extends Itr implements ListIterator<E>`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/AbstractList.java#390)
- `HashSet` - actually backed by [`HashMap.keySet()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/AbstractMap.java#317)

Becasue `Iterator` is an interface, you can do fancy things with it, like wrapping and decorating it, without paying attention to the actual implementation.

Comment: But the point is that the implementation is deliberately hidden from the user, so it can be changed and modified and messed with without breaking any client code.  That's an example of _really good practice._

Comment: Tomasz, can you elaborate it bit please..?

Comment: @LouisWasserman: exactly. See my added example about decorating existing iterator - as long as your decorator follows the API, client couldn't care less

Comment: @PaddyREC: what exactly do you want me to elaborate on? The implementation is hidden in private classes inside appropriate collections. You can see the JDK source and analyze them. But as I said, no need to look at them, thay just work :-).

Comment: @PaddyREC: the implementation is inside the source code of those classes, but it's `private` -- it's not visible or usable from outside those classes.  You can call the `iterator()` method to have the object provide you with an iterator, but you can't see how it does it or create one for yourself.  That's deliberate, good practice.

Answer (score 1):

The `Iterator` interface is implemented as a *inner* and *private* (should be but not necessarily) class *in* the class/interface that implements the `java.lang.Iterable<T>` interface. The method of `Iterable<T>` - `Iterator<T> iterator()` allows an object to be the target of the "foreach" statement.

For more information read the blog of @Andreas Grech : [Java's Iterators and Iterables](http://blog.dreasgrech.com/2010/03/javas-iterators-and-iterables.html)